# Dynamics CRM 2011 - Processes updating non-form fields?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm evaulating Dynamics CRM 2011 currently so I'm still learning how things work.

If a field marked as read-only on a form, is it possible to update it via a process step "update record"? I was trying to have some sort view-only fields that get dynamically updated via a process but in the interface those fields are not accessible to be set?

What if I wrote my own plug-in - would these fields still not be updateable via the assembly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to update a readonly field with a workflow, you have to set it writable until you have the workflow configured. The field will then be accessible and you can add your update action. After that you can set the field to readonly again.

Plugins are not affected by this setting because it is only used for the forms.